# Call external function in dylib

Tags: rust, dylib

I have main application with code that looks like this:

```
pub fn load_lib() {
    let dylib = libloading::Library::new("example.dylib") ...
    unsafe { *dylib.get(b"fn_in_dylib") } ...
    // calling function from dylib.
}
pub extern "Rust" fn fn_in_main_app() { ... } // Function that I want to call from dylib
```

`example.dylib` dyliib is loaded successfully and function from dylib is called without any problems.

But here is what I'm trying to do inside dylib:

```
pub extern "Rust" fn fn_in_dylib() {
    fn_in_main_app(); // Here I'm trying to call function defined in main application.
}
extern "Rust" {
    fn fn_in_main_app();
}
```

But this doesn't even compile:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_fn_in_main_app", referenced from:
```

I'm not sure that I'm using the correct way to implement this, so it didn't surprise me when it didn't compile. But I hope it shows what I'm actually trying to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dylibs can't depend on the application that loads them. The dylib dependency graph must be entirely linear, circular depedencies are not allowed. Depending on what you're doing it may be possible to move `fn_in_main_app` to an upstream dependency of the dylib. You could also pass in a function pointer to the dylib:

```rust
pub extern "Rust" fn fn_in_dylib(fn_in_main_app: fn()) {
    (fn_in_main_app)();
}
```

Comment: Okay, it makes sense, now I'm trying to pass function pointer through static variable. Although your suggested way still allows to set static var through a some `init()` function,  maybe it possible to make static var "extern"?

Comment: Okay, seems, it's impossible to declare extern static. I used static variable as fn pointer + extern init function that assigns actual function pointer to static variable. It works.

Comment: MacOS has a notion of "bundles", i.e. plugins, which you can produce by passing `-bundle` to the linker, and which _can_ link against symbols from the main executable - but then of course, the main executable can't link against symbols from the plugin.